# Read only permission to sftp user in specific directory

Tags: permissions, sftp

I want to create specific SFTP user which will have permissions to only read all folders and subfolders in `/var/www/vhosts`. Any help on this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unix systems provide the `chroot` command which allows you to reset the `/` of the user to some directory in the filesystem hierarchy, where they cannot access "higher-up" files and directories.

However in your case, it would appropriate to provide a virtual chroot implemented by the remote shell service. sftp can be easily configured to restrict a local user to a specific subset of the filesystem.

hence in your case, you want to `chroot` let's say, user `foo` user into the `/var/www/vhosts/` directory.

You can set a chroot directory for your user to confine them to the subdirectory `/var/www/vhosts/` like so in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`;

Create user `foo` with password

```
sudo useradd foo
sudo passwd foo
```

Create for SFTP only group

```
$ sudo groupadd sftp_users
```

Add to a user `foo` for SFTP only group

```
$ sudo usermod -G sftp_users foo
```

Change owner, because read/write permission

```
sudo chown root.root /var/www/vhosts/
```

Add permission

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/vhosts/
```

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

`sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment out and add a line like below

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Add at the last

```
Match Group sftp_users
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ChrootDirectory /var/www/vhosts/
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

*(NOTE : `Match` blocks need to be at the **END** of the `sshd_config` file.)*

Restart `ssh` service

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

With this cenfiguration you can ssh into folder `ubuntu` and get files. Can not `put` or `delete`

To sftp in right folder edit `/etc/passwd`. Change line for user `foo` to look like this

```
$ sudo vi /etc/passwd

..
foo:x:1001:1001::/var/www/vhosts/:
..
```

This will change user `foo` home folder to your sftp server folder.

Comment: So I added 
`Match Group sftp
    ChrootDirectory /var/www/vhosts
    AllowTcpForwarding no`

In sshd_config and created user and group as you did but user `foo` has rights to all folders :(

Comment: @Delirium see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your asnwer. But there must be some mistake..

I added `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
    Match Group sftp
    ChrootDirectory /var/www/vhosts
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp` but there is error when I want to restart ssh `/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 92: Directive 'UsePAM' is not allowed within a Match block`

Comment: @Delirium I have clearly mentioned to put `Match.....` section at the **END** of file. Put that code at the end of file and restart it.

Comment: Sorry for my blind eyes, but it works, so really thank you.

Comment: @Rahul this was useful! Is there a way to prevent `sftp` users to change directory when they `sftp` into the server?

Comment: @coffeMug what you are looking for is the `ChrootDirectory` parameter if you want to prevent the user from accessing the parents directories. Here's [a related article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/). If you're looking for some way to only allow flat listing and block the `cd` (change directory) command, I don't know if that's possible with `sshd_config`.